# Remove space from Ui widgets that are not visible

Tags: gwt, google-apps-script

```
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var flex = app.createFlexTable();
  for (var i = 1; i<=30; i++) 
    flex.setWidget(i, 0, app.createButton('Button '+i).setId('Button'+i).setVisible(false));
  app.getElementById('Button1').setVisible(true);

  var submit = app.createButton('Submit');
  app.add(flex).add(submit); 
  return app;
}
```

Produces [this Ui](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzpDdOACmlx45wzF6LulHYiUWz2uV_SlvEpvZWPPeDoKCD5a4s/exec).

How can we eliminate the empty space between the first visible button and the 'Submit' button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The space is coming from the browser specific styling of the various HTML elements, which applies, for example, a `2px` border-spacing to each hidden row. (I'm testing in Chrome; it may be different for other browsers.)

I'd suggest using a CSS reset to clear out all browser-specific styling. A simple one like this fixes  your spacing issue (again, in Chrome):

```
div, table, tbody, tr, td {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Comment: [This is how](https://script.google.com/d/1pbETSYR5vryitZrfH87v6bpx1EXuWewO37VXGuR9ZXXxMLbeLqTvKtTN/edit) I applied it to the google-apps-script Ui.  Shrunk the empty space down a little but not all the way.

Comment: @BryanP - It looks like you're you're applying the CSS to the table only. It needs to be global. You're being thrown off by both the `div` styling *and* the `table` styling. Since it doesn't seem like you can add external stylesheets, can you add the same styling to `app` as well as to the flextable?

Comment: Probably need to add it to every row and cell in the flex table too (the `tr` and `td` elements.)

Comment: Applying to the entire app didn't make a difference and I don't think we can reference the individual rows.  [Result](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwS0KwSO-mkbMpufekSNKOwgR8H9-r1z1wwKQ4xFWmKRh6G1Aw/exec) from applying to just flex table.  Better than nothing.

Comment: Hey Bryan, just as an aside, did you see they have setStyleAttribute*s* now? So you can do `flex.method().method().setStyleAttributes(_noSpace)`

Comment: @Adam ok, so use that instead of calling the custom applyCSS()?

Comment: That's right, you can still define your style objects globally and apply them them with this native method, and I guess do away with the applyCSS() function altogether. But really, use whatever you prefer for readability etc.